# Wsfedsaml2 - Decryption key

Tags: adfs

I'm trying to use this api: https://github.com/auth0/passport-wsfed-saml2 to implement a SSO in my application. 
I've configured an ADFS serve in a virtual box.

When I try to log in it gives de following message: Assertion is encrypted. Please set options.decryptionKey with your decryption private key.

Where do I get this decryption key? I'm little lost.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With what I understood you have to keep your copy of private key either in your codebase or read it from some enviroment variable. 
And in your code

```
passport.use('wsfed-saml2', new wsfedsaml2({
  protocol: "samlp",
    // This is the private key (use case where ADFS
    // is configured for RP token encryption)
    decryptionKey: fs.readFileSync("your+key+path+privateKey")
}, function (profile, done) {
 // ...
}));
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the answer Saurabh! But my question is where do I find the path to my private key. I can't find it.

Comment: The path should be in your codebase. The path should be similar to places you are getting your html/js/images or any other resources.

Comment: https://imgur.com/cLUanvr. I think I will find it here. But the private key is not exportable.

Comment: I'm asking where I generate the private key to put in my codebase.

Comment: you have to first generate public and private keys and afterwards read the file - a good article to read https://www.devglan.com/java8/rsa-encryption-decryption-java

Comment: I've generated it. But I can't export the private key. It stay disabled.